# retrofit 2 @headers error in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I try to add multiple static headers with retrofit 2 (2.3.0) like this :

```
interface WeatherAPI {

    @Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-type:application/json"
    })
    @GET("/data/2.5/weather")
    fun getWeatherForCityName(@Query("q") city: String, @Query("appid") appid: String) : Call<GetWeatherResponse>;

}
```

I have the folowing error :

[image: error]

Any idea of my mistake?

Comment: you can try `"Content-type: application/json"` give a space and check if it works..

Comment: are you sure that this is the line were the error occurs? using `{}` should give you a `Type mismatch`, not a `Unexpected Token`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Braces `{}` isn't needed inside `@Headers`.

Docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#arrays-as-annotation-parameters

Comment: Ok, in Android studio i ha the "type missmatch error". In removre ce braces and it works thx. It's a kotlin syntaxe?

Answer (score 23):

Use below code:

```
@Headers(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-type:application/json"
)
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use:

```
@Headers(value = ["Accept: application/json",
          "Content-type:application/json"])
```

because the headers need an array parameter for it, you are using the wrong syntax in kotlin

Comment: Can you explain your solution, so that other user will find it easier to understand it?

Comment: so sorry to reply you late, declare an array is difference between java and kotlin.